# Azure Authentication failure from local machine only

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to write a C# app to start an Azure Virtual Machine and connect to it with msctsc from my home computer. I found some code, and running it from a virtual machine (Windows 11) on Azure, it works. But at home (Windows 7), it throws an exception:

```
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed:
Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. 
---> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy.
 ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.. 
---> System.Net.WebException: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Von der šbertragungsverbindung k”nnen keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
bei System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
...
```

The code snippet is

```
        ClientSecretCredential cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
        ResourceIdentifier virtualMachineResourceId = VirtualMachineResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vmName);
        VirtualMachineResource virtualMachine = client.GetVirtualMachineResource(virtualMachineResourceId);

        try
        {
            await virtualMachine.PowerOnAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: if the VM is VPN locked, you may have to login to the VPN locally and then try. Or add an inbound rule on that VM to your local IP